# Cannot set field value in assignment expression

Tags: python, syntax, attributes, python-3.8

With Python 3.8 [Assignment Expressions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) have been introduced, allowing to assign values in conditionals and lambdas as such:

```
if x := True:
    print(x)
```

However it appears this does not extends to attribute assignment, as trying to do something like this

```
from typing import NamedTuple 

class Test(NamedTuple): 
    field : bool

test = Test(field=False) 

if test.field := True: 
    print(test.field)
```

Will result in the following error:

```
SyntaxError: cannot use named assignment with attribute
```

Is it really only possible to update attribute in assignment **statements** (as opposed to assignment **expressions**) and if yes why this limitation?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From the pep:

> #### [Differences between assignment expressions and assignment statements](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/#differences-between-assignment-expressions-and-assignment-statements)
>
> Most importantly, since `:=` is an expression, it can be used in contexts where statements are illegal, including lambda functions and comprehensions.
>
> Conversely, assignment expressions don't support the advanced features found in assignment statements:
>
> - Single assignment targets other than a single `NAME` are not supported:
>
>   ```py
>   # No equivalent
>   a[i] = x
>   self.rest = []
>   ```

Seems like it was just made to avoid things that are too complicated (Which is a sign that it should probably be turned into a full statement somewhere). Also, this can already be achieved with `setattr`:

```py
# This is not that readable, but has the same semantics as what you asked for
if (setattr(test, 'field', new_test_field := ...), new_test_field)[1]:
    ...

# More readable with a helper function
def set_member(obj, member_name, new_value):
    setattr(obj, member_name, new_value)
    return new_value

if set_member(test, 'field', ...):
    ...


# But you might have wanted to check the new `test.field`
# instead of what you assigned it (In case it was a getter/setter descriptor)
def set_member(obj, member_name, new_value):
    setattr(obj, member_name, new_value)
    return getattr(obj, member_name)
```

Comment: Apologies for not reading the pep thoroughly enough. The limitations of the assignment expression are unfortunate, but I guess `setattr` is a close second. Thank you!

Comment: This was actually my first attempt to work with assignment expression and the workaround is to use set_member() :) 

Thanks for the answer

Comment: I like pep 572 as it can render code much more elegant, and really don't get why many people refused to see the need.
However, I don't see a logical reason why it shouldn't allow assigning to object attributes or indices / dict slots. This is a mistake IMO.
The setattr() hack is possible but not as nice/natural as could be otherwise.
The pep argues this is on behalf of lambdas/comprehensions, but I don't see what should prevent assigning to a dotted name or similar in such context.