# Cannot use assignment expressions with subscript

Tags: python, syntax-error

```
if session['dp'] := current_user.avatar :
    ^ SyntaxError: cannot use assignment expressions with subscript
```

Why Python forbids this use of walrus operator?

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but the same issue occurs with attribute assignment, and that's discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59019790/  . There's no definitive answer to the "why" of it—just that the PEP designed it that way, and some speculation that that was to "avoid things getting too complicated," i.e. to limit the negative impact on code readability.

Comment: @jez that takes away the ability to do lambda assignments when you have generic type lambdas being passed.  What I mean is, you can do some nifty things with this if it was allowed: `database.cars.where(lambda x: x.car_id := 1).all()`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because, as the alternative name (named expressions) suggests, [the left hand side of the walrus operator is to be a `NAME`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/). Therefore, by definition such expressions as noted in your question as well as, for instance, function calls are not allowed to be assigned in this form.

The documentation also specifies:

> Single assignment targets other than a single `NAME` are **not** supported

To further this argument, one can notice that cPython explicitly [checks](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/87d3b9db4ade1aa100ee6f065082cb7e85b8992f/Python/ast.c#L1855) if the expression is `Name_kind`:

```
if (target->kind != Name_kind) {
    const char *expr_name = get_expr_name(target);
    if (expr_name != NULL) {
        ast_error(c, n, "cannot use assignment expressions with %s", expr_name);
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: This answers to 'technical why' - because 'they said so'. But why they said so?
I think this is because there is ambiguous meaning for `if` statement: what is correct `if session['dp']:` or `if sesson:`. And to eliminate this ambiguity they deny assignments to anything except plain variable name.

Comment: @AlexeyRuzin that wouldn't be ambiguous since the value of the assignement expression is the value of the right hand side. In this case it would be `current_user.avatar`

Comment: You are right. Have you an idea, why it is not possible though?

Comment: @AlexeyRuzin because they want to prevent people from doing this, the addition of assignment expressions at all was highly contentious, because many people (IMO correctly) believe it would be abused to write terse and unreadable code.

Answer (score 13):

There is some justification for the decision to disallow more complex assignments in assignment expressions given on the python-dev mailing list.

In particular, from Chris Angelico:

> Assignment to arbitrary targets
> would also mean permitting iterable unpacking, which is not desired
> ("x, y := 3, 4"??), and there weren't enough use-cases for
> attribute/item assignment to justify creating a rule of "you can
> assign to any single target, but can't unpack". In the future, if such
> use-cases are found, the grammar can be expanded.

-- https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2018-July/154628.html

and from Guido himself:

> Also nobody had a use case.

-- https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2018-July/154631.html

That's probably as close to an explanation as is possible. Presumably if there's demand the feature may be expanded in some future version.

Comment: +1 for providing a rationale answer. Making small modifications to numpy arrays or pandas dataframes is a fairly large use-case in any kind of data work that may have been overlooked at the time. It is likely worth revisiting.

Comment: @Axoren it certainly wasn't, and in any case, it's no different than any other object that support's other types of assignment targets (attribute, index, etc)

Comment: A use case that comes to mind is manual memoization, of the form `return memo[k] := result_expression`. Surprised that never came up. Or maybe they wanted everyone to use the ol' `@memoized` decorator

Comment: `x, y := 3, 4` doesn't seem any more problematic to me than `1,2 if cond else 3,4`, which is allowed. You can just resolve the ambiguity similarly, by saying `x, y := 3, 4` would be `x, (y := 3), 4` rather than `(x, y) := (3, 4)`. Even aside from whether there are usecases, I find it unexpected that it doesn't work.